# In Android Studio 3.6.1 using Kotlin, System.out.println(CustomArrayList) is not printing values on Debug

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

In previous version of Android Studio, while debugging I could found the Variables values as well as ArrayList values in **variables** window. But now in Android Studio 3.6.1, the ArrayList values is not printing in **variables** window. Hope anyone will have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Log.d instead of println() func. This log.d will print all information of object in logcat for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Use** 
**`println("value : ${list[i]}")`**

**Instead of** **`System.out.println(message)`**

Answer (score 0):

```
val l = arrayListOf<Int>(1,2,3,4,5);
println("Array list contents : ${l.toString()}")
// or use Log.d("Array list": l.toString())
```

Use Log.d() to print into the Logcat !

Comment: Go to file Invalidate and restart once both will work